# Are there any naturally occurring enemies in Mount Celestia's ocean?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planescape

I'm going to have an adventure that's set in Heaven. The party is 3 people, all 9th level. The challenge rating doesn't matter, if it's too high, they can just see it. Hope you can help.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Check out the [tour] and the [help] to learn more about the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any specific information about the seven plateaus of Mount Celestia, nor about the Silver Sea in the 5e *Dungeon Master's Guide*. However, given that the question is tagged *Planescape*, here are a couple of relevant pieces of lore from the 2e Planescape boxed set *Planes of Law*:

> Balaena know the secret portal from the headwaters of the River Oceanus in Thalasia on Elysium to the bottom the Silver Sea.

> The ocean itself is fresh, clean water that burns undead and fiends like holy water ... dolphins and a few sea elves live among the waves. ... Cutters entering Lunia always fall into the ocean; the unready ones are rescued by the zoveri, who ensure that no one who enters the plane drowns without good reason.

[Zoveri](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Zoveri) are interesting creatures that have octupus-like lower body and humanoid upper body. They are said to aid any creatures that fall into the ocean. Balaena are intelligent telepathic gray whales.

Answer (score 2):

#### That depends on your definition of enemy.

There is almost no lore on Celestia to be found in 5th Edition material. Looking back to 3.5e, in the splatbook *Stormwrack*, we see this description of Lunia, first of the seven heavens of Celestia:

> The first of the Seven Heavens, Lunia is girded by the dark, starry Silver Sea. Its shores are dotted with the white citadels and redoubts of Celestia’s residents, and its deeps are home to many good-aligned aquatic creatures, *including celestial whales and aquatic elves.*

Whether or not these are *enemies* is a matter of story building. Motivate your characters to be aligned against sea elves and celestial whales, and you’ve got some natural enemies.